# Creating a nullable<T> extension method ,how do you do it?

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a situation where I need to compare nullable types.
Suppose you have 2 values:

```
int? foo=null;
int? bar=4;
```

This will not work:

```
if(foo>bar)
```

The following works but obviously not for nullable as we restrict it to value types:

```
public static bool IsLessThan<T>(this T leftValue, T rightValue) where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
       return leftValue.CompareTo(rightValue) == -1;
}
```

This works but it's not generic:

```
public static bool IsLessThan(this int? leftValue, int? rightValue)
{
    return Nullable.Compare(leftValue, rightValue) == -1;
}
```

How do I make a Generic version of my `IsLessThan`?

Thanks a lot

Comment: so do you want null < 4 or null > 4 ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static bool IsLessThan<T>(this Nullable<T> t, Nullable<T> other) where T : struct
{
    return Nullable.Compare(t, other) < 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to make the return read Nullable.Compare(t, other) < 0 in order to comply with the Compare documentation. The Compare method is supposed to return a value less than 0 for the "less than case". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxxt7t2a.aspx

Comment: @SeanThoman .Thank you.It works.I did write what you suggested but didnt work ,I must have written something different.thanks

Comment: I am getting exception message saying "The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable<T>'."

Comment: @KasimHusaini how did you solve that error ?

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez, I wasn't able to fix the issue.

Comment: compiler says that C# 9.0 must be used in order to allow that syntax.

Answer (score 2):

It can be simplified:

```
public static bool IsLessThan<T>(this T? one, T? other) where T : struct
{
    return Nullable.Compare(one, other) < 0;
}
```

Comment: you will need C# version 9.0 for this to work